# How to set the style -webkit-transform dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webkit

I want to change the `-webkit-transform: rotate()` property using JavaScript dynamically, but the commonly used `setAttribute` is not working:

```
img.setAttribute('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(60deg)');
```

The `.style` is not working either...

How can I set this dynamically in JavaScript?

Comment: wont you set style attribute instead of just this one

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The JavaScript style names are `WebkitTransformOrigin` and [`WebkitTransform`](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariJSRef/WebKitCSSTransformValue/WebKitCSSTransformValue.html)

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-2deg)";
```

Check the DOM extension reference for WebKit [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs).

Comment: If you want more then one, seperate with a space
For example:

`element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-2deg) translateX(100px)";`

Comment: This works fine on Safari and Chrome, but won't work on Firefox. What is the equivalent way of doing this for Firefox?

Comment: MozTransform should be your friend.

Comment: @Olafur The Apple link is dead.

Comment: So is the only way to do this with a string. Seems like it would be pretty slow if it was recursive.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the first link: it's not available on internet archive. Closest I could find is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/webkitcssmatrix paragraph, or Mozilla doc at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 94):

Here are the JavaScript notations for most common vendors:

```
webkitProperty
MozProperty
msProperty
OProperty
property
```

I reset inline transform styles like:

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "";
element.style.MozTransform = "";
element.style.msTransform = "";
element.style.OTransform = "";
element.style.transform = "";
```

And like this using jQuery:

```
$(element).css({
    "webkitTransform":"",
    "MozTransform":"",
    "msTransform":"",
    "OTransform":"",
    "transform":""
});
```

See blog post *[Coding Vendor Prefixes with JavaScript](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/03/coding-vendor-prefixes-with-javascript/)* (2012-03-21).

Comment: jQuery automatically picks the right prefix, only have to write `transform`.

Comment: @Blaise That is new. Starting from what version?

Comment: It does since jQuery 1.8.0. [Commit on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/5376a809c0d2bee4b7872847c2821e458dfdcc3b)

Comment: `win.style.transform ="translate(-50%)"` not working

Answer (score 12):

Try using

```
img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(60deg)"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it via `setAttribute` you would change the `style` attribute like so:

```
element.setAttribute('style','transform:rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)') //etc
```

This would be helpful if you want to reset all other inline style and only set your needed style properties' values again, BUT in most cases you may not want that. That's why everybody advised to use this:

```
element.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
element.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(90deg)';
```

The above is equivalent to

```
element.style['transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
element.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
```

Answer (score 2):

**To animate your 3D object, use the code:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var x = 100;
    var y = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    x += 1;
    y += 1;
    var element = document.getElementById('cube');
    element.style.webkitTransform = "translateZ(-100px) rotateY("+x+"deg) rotateX("+y+"deg)"; //for safari and chrome
    element.style.MozTransform = "translateZ(-100px) rotateY("+x+"deg) rotateX("+y+"deg)"; //for firefox
},50);
//for other browsers use:   "msTransform",    "OTransform",    "transform"

});

</script>
```