# Converting  a webkit  transition from CSS to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

For the following HTML:

```
<li id="li1">
    <div id="card-container">
        <div id="card">
            <div class="front">
            <img id="track_image" src="image.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div id="controls">
                <audio controls></audio>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</li>
```

I have the following CSS, which will flip it on hover.

```css
#card-container:hover .back {   
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

#card-container:hover .front {      
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
```

But I want to change it so the flip instead happens on a click, I've attached a click listener and am trying this code below but it doesn't do anything

```
function click(evt, listElementId) {
       var listElement = document.getElementById(listElementId);
       var front = listElement.getElementsByClassName("front")[0];
       front.style.webkitTransition = "rotateX(-180deg)";
       var back = listElement.getElementsByClassName("back")[0];
       back.style.webkitTransition = "rotateX(0deg)"
```

What should the JavaScript be to achieve the same as the CSS is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused `transition`s and `transform`ations. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/708895/1048572), you should use

```
front.style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(-180deg)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class:

```css
#card-container.flipped .back {   
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

#card-container.flipped .front {      
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
```

```javascript
function click(evt, listElementId) {
    document.getElementById(listElementId).classList.add('flipped');
}
```

Comment: Still nothing happens when I try that.

Comment: @minitech: You might use `.toggle()` :-)

Comment: @Aminoacids: How did you attach the listener? Show us the code. Also, does you UA support `classList`?