# Safari - jQuery Added CSS Transform Not Working

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I am adding a transform to an element using jQuery, works in all browser but does nothing in Safari. I've looked around for an answer, but cannot find a solution or anyone really talking about this. Here is my code that is not working:

```
$('.element').css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(200px,0px,0px);
```

Transform works if I add it directly to the CSS, but it seems that it isn't even showing up when using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a quote and a closing parenthesis at the end there.

```
$('.element').css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(200px,0px,0px)");
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript).