# Any way to achieve CSS 3D transform with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to rotate an image in 3D and this is possible in css with

```
transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(10deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(10deg);
```

Currently I am using a canvas and the .style.transform property does not work for me. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/chung9ey/31/ . Note: I don't want to have a css file or style tags at all.

Comment: You could transform the canvas instead of the image:  https://jsfiddle.net/q6eyfpce/

Comment: There's a good answer to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14585866/4120837

Alternatively you can use the canvas' built-in transform functions. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_transform.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically correct, but instead of `img.style.transform`, transform the canvas with `canvas.style.transform`:

```js
var img = new Image;
var canvas = document.getElementById("hello");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

img.onload = function(){
 canvas.style.transform = "perspective(50px) rotateX(10deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(10deg)";
 context.drawImage(img, 0 ,0, 500, 300); 
}

img.src = "https://www.enterprise.com/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png";
```

```html
<canvas id = "hello" width = "500px" height = "300px" style="border: 1px solid BLACK";></canvas>
```