# Set style of -webkit using pure JavaScript using element.style.(?) = "stuff";

Tags: javascript

is it possible to style a -webkit css property with .style? or setAtrrtibute() is the way to go?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the style -webkit-transform dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of getting an object's or element's property with brackets: `object["property"]` works the same as `object.property`. In the string, there is allowed to have a dash at the start.

To set a '-webkit' style property, just use `element.style["-webkit..."] = "a value"`.