# How to access keyframes & webkit transform in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

I want to create a circular progressbar in Html, Javascript and css.

This here is my code:

```
<div class="progress blue"> <span class="progress-left"> <span class="progress-bar"></span> </span> <span class="progress-right"> <span class="progress-bar"></span> </span>
                  <div class="progress-value">70%</div>
              </div>
```

```
@keyframes loading-2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
        transform: rotate(50deg)
    }
}
```

I have found following answer to my question on stackoverflow

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-2deg)";
```

but I have 2 keyframes and 2 webkit transform elements, so how can I select the 2nd one?

the 1 that I want to access is the

```
100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
        transform: rotate(50deg)
    }
```

how can I do this in javascript so I can make my progress bar dynamically?

I tried to use this answer here:
[How to set the style -webkit-transform dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript)

but as I said I have 2 keyframe elemnts and 2 webkit transform elements and I cant acces them with
element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-2deg)";

Comment: you no more need the -webkit version, remove it

Answer (score -1):

You can set a classe from your JavaScript with your parameters?

Put this code in your js:

```
document.querySelector(".progress").classList.add(".newClasse")
```

Put this code in your css:

```
.newClasse {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```